# Custom Property of User Control not accessible in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I want to create a Custom User control (`UserControl`) with custom property (`MyLabel`) in WPF using C# without writing any code behind. But my custom property `MyLabel` is inaccessible in **MainWindow.xaml** when I'm using my custom control. What is the problem in my code? If my implementation is wrong then how to achieve this?

**UCControl.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class UCControl:UserControl
    {
        public String MyLabel
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(MyLabelProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyLabelProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyLabelProperty =
            DependencyProperty
                .Register(
                    "MyLabel",
                    typeof(string),
                    typeof(UCControl),
                    new PropertyMetadata(""));

        public UCControl()
        {
            MyLabel = "default label";
        }
    }
}
```

**UserControl1.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:UCControl/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyLabel}" FontSize="18"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid >
        <local:UserControl1 MyLabel="Hello World"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: `public class UCControl:UserControl` is the the code behind of `<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1" ...>`

Comment: UCControl is not matching UserControl1.

Comment: Besides that, write `Text="{Binding MyLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`

Comment: @Clemens  I didn't get you first comment.

Comment: You are showing us the code behind of a UserControl called UCControl, but the XAML of a UserControl called UserControl1. How does that fit together? If that is really your code, it looks really odd. Move the MyLabel property to the code behind of UserControl1, i.e. into the file UserControl1.xaml.cs, and do not set the DataContext property of the Grid in UserControl1.xaml.

Comment: @Clemens Instead of UserControl1.xaml.cs I wanted the code behind to be UCControls.cs.

Comment: Remove the `<Grid.DataContext> <local:UCControl/> </Grid.DataContext>`. This creates a new instance of UCControl. This not what you want. If this control does not depend on an external DataContext, then add `this.DataContext = this` to the constructor of UCControl.

Comment: @SuveenKumar That is not how it works. See my answer.

Comment: @BionicCode `DataContext = this` in a UserControl, seriously?? You know that that breaks any DataContext-based Bindings of the control's properties. Also note that UserControl1 and UCControl are really supposed to be different classes here - which does however make no sense.

Comment: My question is can i do this without writing any line of code in UserControl1.xaml.cs??

Comment: You can't. MyLabel must be a property declared in UserControl1. Or you won't be able to write `<local:UserControl1 MyLabel="Hello World"/>`.

Comment: Thanks Clemens that clears my doubt.

Comment: @Clemens I know. That's why I added the hint: *"If this control does not depend on an external DataContext ..."*. If the control has an isolated DataContext then why not, it's his decision I think.

Comment: You could however write a UserControl with elements in its XAML that bind directly to properties of the current DataContext object, like your `<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyLabel}" />`, where MyLabel is a property of the DataContext inherited from the MainWindow instance, and you would just write `<local:UserControl1 />`.

Comment: @BionicCode OP wants to set the property from the MainWindow.

Comment: @Clemens I definitly don't disagree with you. The code just looked soo odd to me. To me it appeared that UCControl and UserControl1 were the same control and he was trying to set the DataContext to the control itself. Based on this assumption I pointed out that he created a new instance of the control and gave an option how to achieve what I tghought he was trying to do.

Comment: @Clemens  Of course, if UCControl and UserControl1 are different controls then this doesn't make any sense. The whole question looks confused to me: he's setting MyLabel on UserControl1 in MainWindow but this property does not exist. I really thought he meant UCControl and UserControl1 are the same. I'm not sure how your answer fits his question if he needs both controls (if they are supposed to be individual types). Who knows.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
<local:UserControl1 MyLabel="Hello World"/>
```

**requires** that `MyLabel` is a property of the `UserControl1` class.

You have to declare the property of the class declaration of UserControl1, i.e. in the file `UserControl1.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyLabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(MyLabel),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(UserControl1));

    public string MyLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyLabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyLabelProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

You would bind to that property in the UserControl's XAML by

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyLabel,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```